# Extended version of existing jQuery scroll To Element

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I saw this cool jQuery scroll To Element script on stackoverflow :

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});

<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                //$(this).animate(function(){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
                    }, 2000);
                //});
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="div1" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
        Test
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="div2" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
        Test 2
    </div>
    <button id="click">Click me</button>
</html>
```

I want to improve it by making several click buttons and several divs to scroll to.
In other words (this is not proper css but just to get the idea more clear)...

```
<!-- scrollTop: $("#div1[article#{get the article number}]").offset().top -->

<div id="div1[article#01]" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
<div id="div1[article#02]" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
<div id="div1[article#03]" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">

<button id="click[article#01]">Click me</button>
<button id="click[article#02]">Click me</button>
<button id="click[article#03]">Click me</button>
```

thanks !

Comment: clicking on Nth button should scroll to Nth div - is this your intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<div id="article#01" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">hiiiiiii</div>
<div id="article#02" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">hiiiiiii</div>
<div id="article#03" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">hiiiiiii</div>

<button id="click[article#01]">Click me</button>
<button id="click[article#02]">Click me</button>
<button id="click[article#03]">Click me</button>
```

Script

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var id=this.id.split('[');
    var d_id=id[1].split(']')
    var ii=d_id[0]
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[id='+ii+']').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DBfKz/21/)

Comment: Perfect Man ! Thank you both for the quick help ! Sorry that I can't vote up.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are asking.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
   var div_id = $(this).attr('id').substr("click", "div1");
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#" + div_id).offset().top
    }, 2000);
})
```

Comment: Perfect Man ! Thank you both for the quick help ! Sorry that I can't vote up.